# ¿Sólo estar durmiendo es mejor que estar dormido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Aun a día de hoy se sigue hablando de aquella famosa anécdota de don Camilo, ya mencionada en este sitio [en otra ocasión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8243/12637):

> *"No es lo mismo estar dormido que estar durmiendo, como no es lo mismo estar jodido que estar jodiendo."*

A pesar de tener un ejemplo tan rotundo, la gente sigue dando opiniones diversas al respecto de si ambas expresiones son equivalentes o no, y por regla general el significado tanto de *estar durmiendo* como de *estar dormido* se sigue considerando el mismo.

Desde mi punto de vista, el símil sería que "estar durmiendo" se aplicaría (al igual que "estar jodiendo") como si el verbo fuera transitivo y requiriera de un objeto directo sobre el que realizar la acción, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

> No me molestéis ahora que estoy durmiendo al niño.

Es decir, se usa *[dormir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E9e9ZKl)* en su novena acepción: "hacer que alguien se duerma". Sin embargo, al usar el participio "estar dormido" se entiende el verbo en su primera acepción (como verbo intransitivo): "hallarse en el estado de reposo que consiste en la inacción o suspensión de los sentidos y de todo movimiento voluntario".

El hecho de que el verbo se pueda usar también como pronominal creo que añade aún más a la confusión: también se puede decir "se está usted durmiendo", que implicaría que la persona está en proceso de llegar a dicho estado de reposo.

En todo caso, no es el propósito de esta pregunta el tratar de llegar a una conclusión al respecto, sino de entender el porqué. **¿Qué tiene el verbo dormir que provoque esta confusión? ¿Ha existido esta confusión desde que existe el castellano o ha sido algo reciente? ¿Existen otros verbos en castellano que provoquen la misma confusión?**
Por supuesto, excluyendo a los sinónimos de *dormir*, como *[sobar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y44QXth)*.

Yo diría que la causa son las acepciones 10 y 11, que implican un uso transitivo del verbo pero en el que la acción recae sobre el propio sujeto: *dormir la siesta* y *dormir la mona* son los ejemplos que da el DRAE. Pero mantengo la pregunta para conocer vuestras respuestas.

Ya un poco como offtopic, resulta espectacular la definición de "dormir" según el [Diccionario de Autoridades](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1996/diccionario-de-autoridades) (1726-1739):

> **DORMIR.** v. n. Tomar reposo y descansar la misma naturaleza, quando pierde el uso de los sentídos, para recobrar las fuerzas, agotadas por la vigilia o el cansáncio: lo qual se cáusa levantando al celebro ciertos vapores que le ocupan, y digeridos allí, se vuelven a derramar por el cuerpo hechos espíritus.

Comment: genial esa última definición. Por cierto que dice "celebro", pensé que era error tuyo de transcripción pero no, está así en el original, en la edición escaneada también. Y acabo de descubrir que existe en el DLE actual también como forma en desuso sinónimo de *cerebro*

Comment: @blonfu celebro que te guste. :-D Por cierto, la definición está fusilada de la de Covarrubias (1611): "DORMIR es suspender los sentidos con el sueño, el qual la naturaleza dio al animal para recrear los espiritus, y rehacer las fuerças corporales, levantando al celebro ciertos vapores que le ocupan, y dixeridos alli, y espiritualizados se buelven a derramar por todo el cuerpo".

Answer (score 4):

La peculiaridad del verbo *dormir* es que la forma transitiva o reflexiva indican tránsito, mientras que la intransitiva indica el estado final. Ahora mismo no se me ocurre ningún otro verbo que funcione así. Cela, naturalmente, estaba haciendo una broma a costa del presidente del Senado, estableciendo un falso paralelismo entre ambos verbos.

Comment: Descansa / está descansando -- quizás son algo semejantes.

Answer (score -1):

Se me ocurren los verbos **coser** y **cocer**.  Por cierto, Carlos Alejo, gracias por esta interesante pregunta, y a Gorpik por su punto de vista.

Para aclarar, *es mi opinión*, que cualquier verbo en que su **gerundio y  participio** puedan usarse para describir **el estado y la acción de la primera persona**, e.g.,está durmiendo (gerundio), está dormido (*participio*), cumplen las condiciones.

La polémica sería si la acción puede al mismo tiempo ser transitiva y reflexiva:

- estás durmiendo (te estás durmiendo)? estás dormido.
- estás cociendo
  (te estás cociendo)? estás cocido!

Nota como contra-ejemplo:  *estás cabalgando (no te estás cabalgando a tí mismo) pero puedes ser cabalgado por otro*!