# ¿Qué contexto histórico o corriente de pensamiento afectó a la RAE a finales del siglo XVIII?

Tags: historia, rae, dle

Hago esta pregunta sabiendo que puede ser off-topic, pero no quería dejar de compartir una curiosidad que descubrí hace unos días. En una [pregunta anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18064/12637) comenté una definición ciertamente curiosa del verbo dormir, aparecida en la primera versión del diccionario de la RAE. Esta definición se mantuvo en el diccionario hasta su versión de 1783, la cual decía así:

> **DORMIR.** Tomar reposo y descansar la misma naturaleza, quando pierde el uso de los sentidos, para recobrar las fuerzas, agotadas por la vigilia, ó el cansancio: lo qual se causa levantando al celebro ciertos vapores que le ocupan, y digeridos allí, se vuelven a derramar por el cuerpo hechos espíritus.

Esta definición, que hoy día nos parece ciertamente increíble, se vio drásticamente modificada en la siguiente versión del diccionario de la RAE (1791), apenas ocho años más tarde:

> **DORMIR.** Quedar en aquel reposo natural, que llamamos sueño, el qual consiste en cierta inacción, ó suspensión de todos los sentidos y de todo movimiento voluntario. Úsase también como recíproco.

Semejante variación en la definición me hace pensar que a finales del siglo XVIII tuvo que haber una fuerte corriente de pensamiento que afectó profundamente a los catedráticos que componían el diccionario de la academia. O eso o que recibió fuertes críticas por la definición anterior por parte de algunos sectores de la sociedad. **¿Alguien sabe qué pudo ser el motor que causara que la RAE modificara de semejante forma el diccionario en aquella época? ¿Qué circunstancias históricas culminaron con una revolución en las definiciones que se venían arrastrando durante todo el siglo XVIII?**

Estas modificaciones se pueden ver a lo largo de todo el diccionario. Otro ejemplo claro es la definición de "dios" en 1783:

> **DIOS.** Nombre sagrado del primer y supremo ente necesario, eterno é infinito, cuyo ser como se puede comprehender no se puede definir, y solo se puede sacar de sus sagrados oráculos, que es el que es principio y fin de todas las cosas: que crió el universo por su poder, que le conserva por su bondad, que le rige por su providencia, que todo pende de su voluntad, y procede de su magnificencia infinita.
>
> **DIOS.** Entre los Gentiles se dió este nombre, aunque impropiamente, á qualquiera de las falsas Deidades que fingió la idolatría; como el DIOS Apolo, el DIOS Marte.

Y que en 1791 se suavizó a:

> **DIOS.** Nombre sagrado del supremo ser, Criador del Universo que le conserva y rige por su providencia. 2. Entre los Gentiles se dió este nombre á qualquiera de las falsas deidades que veneraban; como: el DIOS Apolo, el DIOS Marte [...].

Answer (score 3):

https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siglo_XVIII.

> Literatura racionalista: Voltaire y otros ilustrados propugnan una literatura útil, instructiva y racional, contraria a las fantasías y con una firme base en los hechos reales o verídicos. Sus ideas se extienden por todo el continente.

Lo que pasó se llama **Siglo de las luces**.

Un querer romper con lo etéreo y supersticioso. Quizá a España llegó más tarde que en el resto de Europa (como siempre). Puede que la aún presente Santa Inquisición (1478-1821) tuviese parte de culpa en esto.

La RAE estaba bajo la protección del mismísimo rey Felipe V. Es fácil deducir que con tal padrino, la Iglesia no estuviese lejos. Por eso podemos ver definiciones tan "poéticas" durante ese siglo (la RAE se funda en 1713). Y aun con una corriente que apela al empirismo galopando por toda Europa, la Iglesia aún tendría cierta influencia.

Durante el período de la Revolución Francesa (1789-1799), viendo lo que sucedia con la monarquía de aquel país, es probable que permitiesen cierta laxitud en algunos campos de las ciencias y de las letras.

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta, sinceramente. Creo que tiene algunos flecos, como el hecho de que la ejecución de Luis XVI fue posterior a los cambios en el DRAE, lo que hace que el último párrafo quede un poco descolgado, pero por lo demás parece un buen punto de inicio.

Comment: Bueno, la Revolución francesa no se remite a un año solo. Antes de ser ejecutado estuvo exiliado (se fugó). Eso ya debería servir de aviso a otras monarquías. Podríamos ver términos que hubiesen cambiado a posteriori (1793 en adelante) y ver en qué grado lo hicieron. Quizá el cambio fuese más significativo que los cambios anteriores.

Comment: He reconducido ese párrafo. Lo he contextualizado. Mejor así que vincular la respuesta a un echo puntual (la decapitación de Luis XVI)

Comment: En el caso de *dormir*, la definición más antigua es de hecho "correcta" según las ideas de la época sobre la fisiología humana (es decir, no entraba en ella ninguna superstición ni dogma religioso, aunque por supuesto no era "científica" según hoy usaríamos ese término).